# Can I "find-file //hostname/dirname/filename"

Tags: microsoft-windows, find-file

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32); local host is MS Windows 7; remote machines are all running variants of MS Windows.

I would swear I've used this syntax (most recently less than a month ago) but it "no longer works" (or I no longer remember.) The Windows explorer shows that the hostname, dirname, and filename exist and are accessible.

I've even forgotten the name of the access method indicated by "//hostname" so my net searches are less than useful.

I *could* "net use 'g:' '\hostname\dirname' /persist:yes" but I consider that a gross hack to be used only in the case I can't get the easier (for me) direct naming mechanism to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grrr. This worked. (Just had to keep adding slashes until it worked.)

```
find-file //hostname/dirname
```

The clue is in the colour of the prepended slashes; I started with eight back-slashes (which worked). After that, any number of fore- or back-slashes which rendered as two [dark] slashes would correctly open the dirname.

The machine maybe has the vapours.

Comment: You can accept your own anser so that the question will be marked as solved.